# Array rotate with juggling algorithm fails

Tags: java, arrays, debugging, rotation

This question is from G4G array rotation. I am getting an error in the second loop telling me the array is getting out of scope. But I don't understand why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class timba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, d;
        n = sc.nextInt();
        d = sc.nextInt();

        int[] arr = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        while (d > 0) {
            int t;
            t = arr[0];
            for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
               arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            }
            arr[n-1] = t;
            d--;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the second loop, `j + 1` index will be out of bounds once j hits arr.length - 1 since indices start from 0, therefore it should be `j < arr.length - 1`

Answer (score 0):

This should be your exception:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 out of bounds for length 6
    at timba.main(timba.java:30)
```

This is caused because your code is letting me input 7 elements when I only specified I want to input 6. Have a look at this line.

```java
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
}
```

Say I specified that n is 5 so the length of the array is 5, but, this is letting me input 6. This can simply be fixed by adding a -1 to the code.

```java
for(int i=0;i<arr.length - 1;i++){
    arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
}
```

Next bit of code we have to look at is

```
for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
    arr[j]=arr[j+1];
}
```

This is a common mistake that beginner Java programmers make. This will always go out of bounds because when j = 4, then "arr[4] = array[5]" but your array only goes up to arr[4] because I only wanted to input 5 elements. That's why the compiler gave you that exception. You can fix this by adding a "-1" just like the previous mistake you made and this should fix this exception.

```java
for(int j=0;j<arr.length - 1;j++){
    arr[j]=arr[j+1];
}
```

Your new code should be

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class timba {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n,d;
        n=sc.nextInt();
        d=sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr= new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length - 1;i++){
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        while(d>0){
            int t;
            t=arr[0];
            for(int j=0;j<arr.length - 1;j++){
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];

            }

            arr[n-1]=t;
            d--;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This should be it for the exceptions, but you also need to fix the code's functionality as it is not giving you the answer that it is supposed to. I think that it can be fixed with just a little bit more of revising and changing the while loop (int t might be causing the problem.)

I hope you enjoy your journey with Java. Have a great day and remember to stay safe!